# Dropdown in php using odbc is not sending selected value to another php page

Tags: php, forms, odbc

I am trying to display value in drop down from database using ODBC and send to another page but it is not working. 
Code is able to get values from database and display but unable to send to ResultsL2.php page.

On ResultsL2.php page, value is shown as blank.
Any help to resolve this is appreciated. Thanks

```
<form action="ResultsL2.php" method="post">
<select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_43" name="Testing">
<?php
$connect = odbc_connect("<hostname>", "<username>", "<password>");
$query="SELECT testname FROM RESULT group by 1;";
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
$pre_name=" ";
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)){
    $pre_name .= "<option value=".odbc_result($result,'testname').">" . odbc_result($result,'testname'). "</option>";
   }
print "<option value=\"$pre_name\">$pre_name</option>";
odbc_close($conn);
?>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">;
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you see any PHP Errors or Connection Errors? Do you see any browser console errors when you hit `Submit`? What is the code doing in your ResultsL2.php page? What do you see if you use `var_export($_POST);`?

Comment: Thanks Twisty. Used your suggestion to see values on ResultsL2.php page and found that values were actually getting store in "Testing". I was trying to catch pre_name. Solution is that on ResultsL2.php, I had to use temppre = $_POST['testing']; to capture the selected value. I was doing $_POST["pre_name"].

Comment: That would make sense since you have `name="Testing"` as an attribute of your `select`. I do not see "pre_name" as an attribute of any of your form elements.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably how you are using your quotes.  Try this...

```
$pre_name .= '<option value="'.odbc_result($result,'testname').'">' . 
 odbc_result($result,'testname') . '</option>';
```

The values are expecting their own quotes to indicate strings.

Comment: It is not working. It is displaying drop down values with " and duplicates. Dropdown values part is working fine and getting pulled from table and displayed correctly. Problem is that when value is selected, I want to send to ResultsL2.php. That is not happening.

Comment: Had a type that I fixed. Not sure it will make a difference.  Good luck.